# Issue in Spring page navigation Mapping not found error in logs

Tags: spring, maven, http-status-code-404

[image]I am new to Spring and trying one user registration example using maven with spring mvc.
I am able to lunch my home page but when i click on the login link than getting 404 error page not found.
Below are my application details:-

Web.xml

```
<web-app id = "WebApp_ID" version = "2.4"
   xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

      <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

DispacterServlet:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath.*:jbr/config/user-beans.xml" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="jbr.springmvc" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Controller:-

```
package jbr.springmvc.controller;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import jbr.springmvc.model.Login;
import jbr.springmvc.model.User;
import jbr.springmvc.service.UserService;
@Controller
public class LoginController {
  @Autowired
  UserService userService;
  @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView showLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("login");
    mav.addObject("login", new Login());
    return mav;
  }
  @RequestMapping(value = "/loginProcess", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView loginProcess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
  @ModelAttribute("login") Login login) {
    ModelAndView mav = null;
    User user = userService.validateUser(login);
    if (null != user) {
    mav = new ModelAndView("welcome");
    mav.addObject("firstname", user.getFirstname());
    } else {
    mav = new ModelAndView("login");`enter code here`
    mav.addObject("message", "Username or Password is wrong!!");
    }
    return mav;
  }
}
```

Login.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
            <title>Login</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form:form id="loginForm" modelAttribute="login" action="loginProcess" method="post">
                <table align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <form:label path="username">Username: </form:label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <form:input path="username" name="username" id="username" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <form:label path="password">Password:</form:label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <form:password path="password" name="password" id="password" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <form:button id="login" name="login">Login</form:button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><a href="home.jsp">Home</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form:form>
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-style: italic; color: red;">${message}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
        </html>
```

I have tried so many some but not able to find any solution for this.
Please help me to identify where I am doing wrong.It's my first application in spring so not able to perform any more analysis.
Please guide me with this

Comment: is your WEB-INF folder empty ?  Your jsp's should be located in there

Comment: Please Share your pom file as well

Answer (score 0):

You Have specified home.jsp in your welcome file list. I don't see a home.jsp file in your file path. May be that's throwing you 404. You have a login.jsp. Make your controller return "login" from your controller. Either wise works. Since you mentioned as a beginner, you can check here for bootstrapping a basic app.

https://github.com/mrakhunathan/SpringWebSkeleton.git